# Add suffix for TCL list

Tags: algorithm, list, tcl

I have a list contain a list.

```
{
    {1, A},
    {2, A},
    {4, A},
    {6, B},
    {2, B},
    {7, C}
}
```

How can I search the second element and add index if duplicated?

Expected output:

```
{
    {1, A<0>},
    {2, A<1>},
    {4, A<2>},
    {6, B<0>},
    {2, B<1>},
    {7, C}
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid Tcl list.

Comment: Do you only want the `<0>` adding if there's more than one entry with that name? Are the elements guaranteed to be contiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tcl 8.6

```
proc update {list} {
    lmap elem $list {
        set val [lindex $elem end]
        set n [expr {[incr count($val)] - 1}]
        lset elem end "$val<$n>"
    }
}

set a {{1 A} {2 A} {4 A} {6 B} {2 B} {7 C}}
set new [update $a]
```

Answer (score 1):

A Tcl list usually doesn't have separators other than whitespace between elements, and where there is a sublist that is represented by items within braces the comma is explicitly forbidden after the sublist.

```
set list {
    {1 A}
    {2 A}
    {4 A}
    {6 B}
    {2 B}
    {7 C}
}

set res {}
foreach item $list {
    set letter [lindex $item 1]
    if {[info exists num($letter)]} {
        incr num($letter)
    } else {
        set num($letter) 0
    }
    lset item 1 $letter<$num($letter)>
    lappend res $item
}
```

The algorithm consists of traversing the list of lists with `foreach` and looking at the letter that is the second element (index #1) in the sublist. An array, `num` is used to count the number of times each letter has occurred. If `num($letter)` exists, we have counted this letter before and simply increases the count. If it doesn't, it's a new letter and we set the count to 0. We write back (using `lset`) the letter together with a suffix containing the count, and finally add the changed sublist to the list `res`.

If you have `lmap`, you can simplify the code a little bit:

```
set res {}
lmap item $list {
    set letter [lindex $item 1]
    if {[info exists num($letter)]} {
        incr num($letter)
    } else {
        set num($letter) 0
    }
    lset item 1 $letter<$num($letter)>
}
```

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)